# React native keychain error when using setGenericPassword function

Tags: java, react-native, keychain, react-native-keychain

I am using [keychain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain) package to store credentials. After I build the app this package doesn't work but throws an error.
This is the error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.oblador.keychain.cipherStorage.CipherStorageFacebookConceal.throwIfInsufficientLevel(com.oblador.keychain.SecurityLevel)' on a null object reference
```

The same code works fine when it is compiled on my friend's pc.
SO, why is that?  We build the same app on the same phone and I got this error.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem by defining the `STORAGE_TYPE`

```
let options: Keychain.Options = { storage:Keychain.STORAGE_TYPE.FB};
```

you can select that will use `FB` ,`AES` or `RSA`

```
Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', "password", options).then(console.log)
```

[image: options]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Omg now It works!!! I thought it was because of how I installed android studio or java.

Comment: Just adding a note here: The 'FB' type is just an obfuscation and is not safe for encrypting sensitive data in production environments. See https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/314#issuecomment-705581503 for more information.